# modify vim highlight priorities

Tags: vim

I have the four following types of highlighting in my `.vimrc` (each one displays different colors):

- incsearch (highlight-as-you-search matches)
- match (current word, a la visual studio editor)
- 2match (trailing spaces at end of line)
- hlsearch (regular `/` search matches)

The priority of highlighting seems to be exactly as I listed above. E.g. incremental search coloring will *override* any of the other matches colors if present in the same character.

I'd like to make `hlsearch` second in priority, so that it overrides both `match` and `2match` colors (if present in the same character).

Is there any way to accomplish that?

For reference, these are the relevant lines in my `.vimrc` file:

```
[...]
set hlsearch
set incsearch
[...]
function Matches()
    highlight curword ctermbg=darkgrey cterm=bold gui=bold guibg=darkgrey
    silent! exe printf('match curword /\V\<%s\>/', escape(expand('<cword>'), '/\'))
    highlight eolspace ctermbg=red guibg=red
    2match eolspace /\s\+$/
endfunction
au CursorMoved * exe 'call Matches()'
[...]
```

Comment: You might be interested in `set list listchars=tab:\ \ ,eol:¶`, which puts a `¶` after each line. I use `set list listchars=tab:▸┈,trail:␣` instead, which unobtrusively makes tabs and trailing spaces visible. That alleviates your need for `2match`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The priority of everything you use is fixed; the only way to specify a priority is via `matchadd()`, which you can use as a replacement for `:match` and `:2match`. As the priority of hlsearch is zero, you need to pass a negative priority, e.g. -1).

For example, replace

```vim
:match Match /\<\w\{5}\>/
```

with

```vim
if exists('w:lastmatch')
    call matchdelete(w:lastmatch)
endif
let w:lastmatch = call matchadd('Match', '\<\w\{5}\>', -1)
```

Comment: That fixes the priorities, but introduces a problem: matchadd won't _replace_ the previous match, instead it **adds** a new one. Therefore, it no longer matches the current word but the current _and all previous_ words.

Comment: You have to remember the returned ID and `matchdelete()` it on the next invocation. You'll probably define a custom `:Match` command for this, anyway, so put this additional logic in there.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Please modify your answer to reflect that matchadd is not equivalent to match when used repeatedly, needing `if exists(g:lastmatch) call matchdelete(g:lastmatch) endif; let g:lastmatch=call matchadd(...)`

Comment: Done. I've used a window-local variable, because the matches are scoped to the window, too. Please don't forget to accept my answer.